# Somthing confused with ole drag and drop implementation

Tags: drag-and-drop, c++builder, ole

I wish to finish a little demo to implement OLE drag and drop(drag a file from my application to windows explorer).

But here comes a problem:DoDragDrop return DRAGDROP_S_DROP which means the ole drag and drop operation has successfully done,but also get DROPEFFECT_NONE which means drop target cannot accept the data.

I debug into it but I get a mess with them,help me,please:(

Here is the gui:
[image]

Critical code comes:
1.MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MainWindowH
#define MainWindowH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <Ole2.h>
#include "MyDataObject.h"
#include "MyDropSource.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TLabel *Label1;
    void __fastcall Label1StartDrag(TObject *Sender, TDragObject *&DragObject);
    void __fastcall Label1EndDrag(TObject *Sender, TObject *Target, int X, int Y);
    void __fastcall FormCreate(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall FormDestroy(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
    //准备两个接口实例
    IDataObject *pDataObject;
    IDropSource *pDropSource;

    //
    STGMEDIUM stgmed;
    FORMATETC fmtetc;

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

2.DoDragDrop invoke in MainWindow.cpp

```
   void __fastcall TForm1::Label1StartDrag(TObject *Sender, TDragObject *&DragObject)
{
    Label1->Caption = "Start drag";

    //Source file
    char tFileName[256] = "D:\\119.dat";

    //Prepare FOTMATETC
    fmtetc.cfFormat = CF_HDROP;
    fmtetc.dwAspect = DVASPECT_CONTENT;
    fmtetc.lindex = -1;
    fmtetc.ptd = (void*)0;
    fmtetc.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;

    //Prepare DROPFILES
    DROPFILES* tDropFiles;
    //Fill the filename
    HGLOBAL hGblFiles;
    LPSTR lpData;
    stgmed.hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GHND, sizeof(DROPFILES)+strlen(tFileName)+ 2);
    if(0 == stgmed.hGlobal)
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "OUT_OF_MEMORY!!!", "OUT_OF_MEMORY", 0);

    tDropFiles = (DROPFILES*)GlobalLock(stgmed.hGlobal);
    ZeroMemory(tDropFiles, sizeof(DROPFILES)+strlen(tFileName)+2);
    strcpy(((char*)tDropFiles)+sizeof(DROPFILES), tFileName);
    GlobalUnlock(stgmed.hGlobal);

    tDropFiles->fNC     = true;
    tDropFiles->fWide   = false;
    tDropFiles->pFiles  = sizeof(DROPFILES);
    tDropFiles->pt.x    = 0;
    tDropFiles->pt.y    = 0;

    //set hGlobal
    stgmed.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
    stgmed.hGlobal = tDropFiles;
    stgmed.pUnkForRelease = 0;

    //Create Instance of IDropSource and IDataObject
    pDropSource  = new MyDropSource();
    pDropSource->AddRef();
    pDataObject  = new MyDataObject();
    pDataObject->AddRef();

    //SetData
    pDataObject->SetData(&fmtetc, &stgmed, true);

    OleInitialize(0);

    //Invoke DoDragDrop
    DWORD dwEffect;
    HRESULT tResult = DoDragDrop((IDataObject*)pDataObject, (IDropSource*)pDropSource, DROPEFFECT_MOVE, &dwEffect);

    //Ckeck drag&drop result
    if(tResult != DRAGDROP_S_DROP)
        {
        if(tResult == DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL)
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "DRAGDROP_S_CANCEL!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
        else
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "E_UNSPEC!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
        return;
        }

    if((dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_MOVE) == DROPEFFECT_MOVE)
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Ole drag&drop OK!!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
    else
        {
        if((dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_NONE) == DROPEFFECT_NONE)
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "DROPEFFECT_NONE!!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
        }

    //Clean
    pDropSource->Release();
    pDataObject->Release();

    OleUninitialize();

    return;
}
```

3.MyDataObject.h

```
#ifndef _MYDATAOBJECT_H_
#define _MYDATAOBJECT_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "IDragDemo.h"
#include "MyDropSource.h"

#ifndef SAFE_DELETE
#define SAFE_DELETE(p) { if(p){delete(p);  (p)=NULL;} }
#endif

HRESULT CreateEnumFormatEtc(UINT cfmt, FORMATETC *afmt, IEnumFORMATETC **ppEnumFormatEtc);

class MyDataObject : public IDataObject
{
public:
    //IUnknown implementation
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
    ULONG __stdcall Release();
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject);

    //IDataObject members
    STDMETHODIMP GetData               (FORMATETC *pformatetcIn, STGMEDIUM *pmedium);
    STDMETHODIMP GetDataHere           (FORMATETC *pformatetc,   STGMEDIUM *pmedium);
    STDMETHODIMP QueryGetData          (FORMATETC *pformatetc);
    STDMETHODIMP GetCanonicalFormatEtc (FORMATETC *pformatectIn, FORMATETC *pformatetcOut);
    STDMETHODIMP SetData               (FORMATETC *pformatetc,   STGMEDIUM *pmedium,  BOOL fRelease);
    STDMETHODIMP EnumFormatEtc         (DWORD     dwDirection,   IEnumFORMATETC **ppenumFormatEtc);
    STDMETHODIMP DAdvise               (FORMATETC *pformatetc,   DWORD advf, IAdviseSink *pAdvSink, DWORD *pdwConnection);
    STDMETHODIMP DUnadvise             (DWORD     dwConnection);
    STDMETHODIMP EnumDAdvise           (IEnumSTATDATA **ppenumAdvise);
public:
    MyDataObject();
    ~MyDataObject();
private:
    LONG refcount;

    FORMATETC* m_AcceptFormat;
    STGMEDIUM* m_StorageMedium;

    HGLOBAL DupGlobalMem(HGLOBAL hMem);

    //Helper function
    HRESULT CopyMedium(STGMEDIUM* pMedDest, STGMEDIUM* pMedSrc, FORMATETC* pFmtSrc);
    HRESULT SetBlob(CLIPFORMAT cf, const void *pvBlob, UINT cbBlob);

    LONG m_RefCount;
};
//----------------MyEnumFormatEtc-----------------------------------------------------------
class MyEnumFormatEtc : public IEnumFORMATETC
{
public:
    // IUnknown members
    HRESULT __stdcall  QueryInterface (REFIID iid, void ** ppv)
    {
        if((iid==IID_IUnknown)||(iid==IID_IEnumFORMATETC))
        {
            *ppv=this;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            *ppv=NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
    }
    ULONG   __stdcall AddRef (void) { return ++_iRefCount; }
    ULONG   __stdcall Release (void)  { if(--_iRefCount==0){delete this;  return 0;} return _iRefCount; }

    // IEnumFormatEtc members
    HRESULT __stdcall  Next  (ULONG celt, FORMATETC * rgelt, ULONG * pceltFetched);
    HRESULT __stdcall  Skip  (ULONG celt)
    {
        _nIndex += celt;
        return (_nIndex <= _nNumFormats) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
    }
    HRESULT __stdcall  Reset (void)
    {
        _nIndex = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }
    HRESULT __stdcall  Clone (IEnumFORMATETC ** ppEnumFormatEtc)
    {
        HRESULT hResult;
        hResult = CreateEnumFormatEtc(_nNumFormats, _pFormatEtc, ppEnumFormatEtc);
        if(hResult == S_OK)
        {
            ((MyEnumFormatEtc *)*ppEnumFormatEtc)->_nIndex = _nIndex;
        }
        return hResult;
    }

    // Construction / Destruction
    MyEnumFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pFormatEtc, ULONG nNumFormats);
    ~MyEnumFormatEtc();

private:
    LONG        _iRefCount;        
    ULONG       _nIndex;        
    ULONG       _nNumFormats;      
    FORMATETC * _pFormatEtc; 
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#endif
```

4.MyDataObject.cpp

```
 #include "MyDataObject.h"
 #include "MyDropSource.h"
 #include <Urlmon.h>


MyDataObject::MyDataObject(MyDropSource* vDropSource)
{
    m_RefCount = 0;
    m_DropSource = vDropSource;
}


MyDataObject::~MyDataObject()
{
    refcount = 0;

    SAFE_DELETE(m_StorageMedium);
    SAFE_DELETE(m_AcceptFormat);
}


ULONG __stdcall MyDataObject::AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&m_RefCount);
}

ULONG __stdcall MyDataObject::Release()
{
    ULONG nRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_RefCount);

    if (nRefCount == 0)
        delete this;

    return nRefCount;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject) {

if (!ppvObject)
        return E_POINTER;

    if (riid == IID_IDataObject)
        *ppvObject = (IDataObject*)this;
    else if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
        *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
    else
    {
        *ppvObject = 0;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    AddRef();
    return S_OK;


}


STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetData(FORMATETC *pformatetcIn, STGMEDIUM *pmedium)
{

    if ( (NULL == pformatetcIn) || (NULL == pmedium) )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    pmedium->hGlobal = NULL;

    if( (pformatetcIn->tymed & m_AcceptFormat->tymed) &&
        (pformatetcIn->dwAspect == m_AcceptFormat->dwAspect) &&
        (pformatetcIn->cfFormat == m_AcceptFormat->cfFormat) )
        {
            return CopyMedium(pmedium, m_StorageMedium, m_AcceptFormat);
        }

    return DV_E_FORMATETC;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetDataHere(FORMATETC *pformatetc, STGMEDIUM *pmedium)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::QueryGetData(FORMATETC *pformatetc)
{
    if(NULL == pformatetc )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if(!(DVASPECT_CONTENT & pformatetc->dwAspect))
    {
        return DV_E_DVASPECT;
    }
    HRESULT hr = DV_E_TYMED;

    if(m_AcceptFormat->tymed & pformatetc->tymed )
        {
        if(m_AcceptFormat->cfFormat == pformatetc->cfFormat )
            {
            return S_OK;
            }
        else
            {
            hr = DV_E_CLIPFORMAT;
            }
        }
    else
        {
            hr = DV_E_TYMED;
        }
    return hr;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetCanonicalFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pformatectIn, FORMATETC *pformatetcOut)
{
    pformatetcOut->ptd = NULL;
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::SetData(FORMATETC *pformatetc, STGMEDIUM *pmedium, BOOL fRelease)
{
    if ( (NULL == pformatetc) || (NULL == pmedium) )
        return E_INVALIDARG;


    if ( pformatetc->tymed != pmedium->tymed )
        return E_FAIL;

    m_AcceptFormat = new FORMATETC;
    m_StorageMedium = new STGMEDIUM;
    ZeroMemory(m_AcceptFormat, sizeof(FORMATETC));
    ZeroMemory(m_StorageMedium, sizeof(STGMEDIUM));

    if ( TRUE == fRelease )
    {
        *m_StorageMedium = *pmedium;
    }
    else
    {
        CopyMedium(m_StorageMedium, pmedium, pformatetc);
    }

    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::EnumFormatEtc(DWORD dwDirection, IEnumFORMATETC **ppenumFormatEtc)
{
    if(NULL == ppenumFormatEtc)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    *ppenumFormatEtc = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;
    if (DATADIR_GET == dwDirection )
    {
        FORMATETC rgfmtetc[] =
        {
            { CF_HDROP, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, 0, TYMED_HGLOBAL },
        };
        hr = CreateEnumFormatEtc(ARRAYSIZE(rgfmtetc), rgfmtetc, ppenumFormatEtc);
    }
    return hr;
}
//Advises:OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED
STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::DAdvise(FORMATETC *pformatetc, DWORD advf, IAdviseSink *pAdvSink, DWORD *pdwConnection)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pformatetc);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(advf);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pAdvSink);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pdwConnection);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::DUnadvise(DWORD dwConnection)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwConnection);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::EnumDAdvise(IEnumSTATDATA **ppenumAdvise)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ppenumAdvise);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
//Advises:OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED

HGLOBAL MyDataObject::DupGlobalMem(HGLOBAL hMem)
{
    DWORD   len    = GlobalSize(hMem);
    PVOID   source = GlobalLock(hMem);
    PVOID   dest   = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT | GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, len);

    memcpy(dest, source, len);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    return dest;
}

HRESULT MyDataObject::CopyMedium(STGMEDIUM* pMedDest, STGMEDIUM* pMedSrc, FORMATETC* pFmtSrc)
{
    if ( (NULL == pMedDest) || (NULL ==pMedSrc) || (NULL == pFmtSrc) )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    switch(pMedSrc->tymed)
    {
    case TYMED_HGLOBAL:
        pMedDest->hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hGlobal, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_GDI:
        pMedDest->hBitmap = (HBITMAP)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hBitmap, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_MFPICT:
        pMedDest->hMetaFilePict = (HMETAFILEPICT)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hMetaFilePict, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_ENHMF:
        pMedDest->hEnhMetaFile = (HENHMETAFILE)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hEnhMetaFile, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_FILE:
        pMedSrc->lpszFileName = (LPOLESTR)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->lpszFileName, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_ISTREAM:
        pMedDest->pstm = pMedSrc->pstm;
        pMedSrc->pstm->AddRef();
        break;
    case TYMED_ISTORAGE:
        pMedDest->pstg = pMedSrc->pstg;
        pMedSrc->pstg->AddRef();
        break;
    case TYMED_NULL:
    default:
        break;
    }
    pMedDest->tymed = pMedSrc->tymed;
    pMedDest->pUnkForRelease = NULL;
    if(pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease != NULL)
    {
        pMedDest->pUnkForRelease = pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease;
        pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease->AddRef();
    }
    return S_OK;
}
HRESULT MyDataObject::SetBlob(CLIPFORMAT cf, const void *pvBlob, UINT cbBlob)
{
    void *pv = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, cbBlob);
    HRESULT hr = pv ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        CopyMemory(pv, pvBlob, cbBlob);
        FORMATETC fmte = {cf, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
        STGMEDIUM medium = {};
        medium.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        medium.hGlobal = pv;
        hr = this->SetData(&fmte, &medium, TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            GlobalFree(pv);
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateEnumFormatEtc(UINT cfmt, FORMATETC *afmt, IEnumFORMATETC **ppEnumFormatEtc)
{
    if (cfmt == 0 || afmt == 0 || ppEnumFormatEtc == 0)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    *ppEnumFormatEtc = new MyEnumFormatEtc(afmt, cfmt);
    return (*ppEnumFormatEtc) ? S_OK: E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}

void DeepCopyFormatEtc(FORMATETC *dest, FORMATETC *source)
{
    *dest = *source;
    if(source->ptd)
    {
        dest->ptd = (DVTARGETDEVICE*)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(DVTARGETDEVICE));
        *(dest->ptd) = *(source->ptd);
    }
}

MyEnumFormatEtc::MyEnumFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pFormatEtc, ULONG nNumFormats)
    :_iRefCount(1),_nIndex(0),_nNumFormats(nNumFormats)
{
    _pFormatEtc  = new FORMATETC[nNumFormats];
    // make a new copy of each FORMATETC structure
    for(ULONG i = 0; i < nNumFormats; i++)
    {
        DeepCopyFormatEtc (&_pFormatEtc[i], &pFormatEtc[i]);
    }
}
MyEnumFormatEtc::~MyEnumFormatEtc()
{
    // first free any DVTARGETDEVICE structures
    for(ULONG i = 0; i < _nNumFormats; i++)
    {
        if(_pFormatEtc[i].ptd)
            CoTaskMemFree(_pFormatEtc[i].ptd);
    }
    // now free the main array
    delete[] _pFormatEtc;
}

HRESULT __stdcall MyEnumFormatEtc::Next(ULONG celt, FORMATETC *pFormatEtc, ULONG *pceltFetched)
{
    ULONG copied = 0;
    // copy the FORMATETC structures into the caller's buffer
    while (_nIndex < _nNumFormats && copied < celt)
    {
        DeepCopyFormatEtc (&pFormatEtc [copied], &_pFormatEtc [_nIndex]);
        copied++;
        _nIndex++;
    }
    // store result
    if(pceltFetched != 0)
        *pceltFetched = copied;
    // did we copy all that was requested?
    return (copied == celt) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}
```

5.MyDropSource.h

```
#ifndef _MYDROPSOURCE_H_
#define _MYDROPSOURCE_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include "IDragDemo.h"

class MyDropSource : public IDropSource
{
public:

    //IUnknown implementation
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
    ULONG __stdcall Release();
    STDMETHODIMP    QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject);

    //IDropSource members
    STDMETHODIMP QueryContinueDrag(BOOL fEscapePressed, DWORD grfKeyState);
    STDMETHODIMP GiveFeedback(DWORD dwEffect);

    //Cons/Destructors
    MyDropSource();
    ~MyDropSource();
private:
    LONG refcount;
};
#endif
```

6.MyDropSource.cpp

```
#include "MyDataObject.h"
 #include "MyDropSource.h"
 #include <Urlmon.h>

//Constructors
MyDataObject::MyDataObject(MyDropSource* vDropSource)
{
    m_RefCount = 0;
    m_DropSource = vDropSource;
}

//Destructors
MyDataObject::~MyDataObject()
{
    refcount = 0;

    SAFE_DELETE(m_StorageMedium);
    SAFE_DELETE(m_AcceptFormat);
}

//IUnkown implementation
ULONG __stdcall MyDataObject::AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&m_RefCount);
}

ULONG __stdcall MyDataObject::Release()
{
    ULONG nRefCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_RefCount);

    if (nRefCount == 0)
        delete this;

    return nRefCount;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject) {
    if (!ppvObject)
    return E_POINTER;

if (riid == IID_IDataObject)
    *ppvObject = (IDataObject*)this;
else if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
    *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
else
{
    *ppvObject = 0;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

AddRef();
return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetData(FORMATETC *pformatetcIn, STGMEDIUM *pmedium)
{
    //入参检查
    if ( (NULL == pformatetcIn) || (NULL == pmedium) )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    pmedium->hGlobal = NULL;

    if( (pformatetcIn->tymed & m_AcceptFormat->tymed) &&
        (pformatetcIn->dwAspect == m_AcceptFormat->dwAspect) &&
        (pformatetcIn->cfFormat == m_AcceptFormat->cfFormat) )
        {
            return CopyMedium(pmedium, m_StorageMedium, m_AcceptFormat);
        }

    return DV_E_FORMATETC;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetDataHere(FORMATETC *pformatetc, STGMEDIUM *pmedium)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::QueryGetData(FORMATETC *pformatetc)
{
    if(NULL == pformatetc )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    if(!(DVASPECT_CONTENT & pformatetc->dwAspect))
    {
        return DV_E_DVASPECT;
    }
    HRESULT hr = DV_E_TYMED;

    if(m_AcceptFormat->tymed & pformatetc->tymed )
        {
        if(m_AcceptFormat->cfFormat == pformatetc->cfFormat )
            {
            return S_OK;
            }
        else
            {
            hr = DV_E_CLIPFORMAT;
            }
        }
    else
        {
            hr = DV_E_TYMED;
        }
    return hr;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::GetCanonicalFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pformatectIn, FORMATETC *pformatetcOut)
{
    pformatetcOut->ptd = NULL;
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::SetData(FORMATETC *pformatetc, STGMEDIUM *pmedium, BOOL fRelease)
{
    if ( (NULL == pformatetc) || (NULL == pmedium) )
        return E_INVALIDARG;


    if ( pformatetc->tymed != pmedium->tymed )
        return E_FAIL;

    m_AcceptFormat = new FORMATETC;
    m_StorageMedium = new STGMEDIUM;
    ZeroMemory(m_AcceptFormat, sizeof(FORMATETC));
    ZeroMemory(m_StorageMedium, sizeof(STGMEDIUM));

    if ( TRUE == fRelease )
    {
        *m_StorageMedium = *pmedium;
    }
    else
    {
        CopyMedium(m_StorageMedium, pmedium, pformatetc);
    }

    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::EnumFormatEtc(DWORD dwDirection, IEnumFORMATETC **ppenumFormatEtc)
{
    if(NULL == ppenumFormatEtc)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    *ppenumFormatEtc = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;
    if (DATADIR_GET == dwDirection )
    {
        FORMATETC rgfmtetc[] =
        {
            { CF_HDROP, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, 0, TYMED_HGLOBAL },
        };
        hr = CreateEnumFormatEtc(ARRAYSIZE(rgfmtetc), rgfmtetc, ppenumFormatEtc);
    }
    return hr;
}
//Advises:OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED
STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::DAdvise(FORMATETC *pformatetc, DWORD advf, IAdviseSink *pAdvSink, DWORD *pdwConnection)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pformatetc);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(advf);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pAdvSink);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pdwConnection);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::DUnadvise(DWORD dwConnection)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(dwConnection);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::EnumDAdvise(IEnumSTATDATA **ppenumAdvise)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ppenumAdvise);
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
//Advises:OLE_E_ADVISENOTSUPPORTED

HGLOBAL MyDataObject::DupGlobalMem(HGLOBAL hMem)
{
    DWORD   len    = GlobalSize(hMem);
    PVOID   source = GlobalLock(hMem);
    PVOID   dest   = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT | GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_DDESHARE, len);

    memcpy(dest, source, len);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    return dest;
}

HRESULT MyDataObject::CopyMedium(STGMEDIUM* pMedDest, STGMEDIUM* pMedSrc, FORMATETC* pFmtSrc)
{
    if ( (NULL == pMedDest) || (NULL ==pMedSrc) || (NULL == pFmtSrc) )
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    switch(pMedSrc->tymed)
    {
    case TYMED_HGLOBAL:
        pMedDest->hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hGlobal, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_GDI:
        pMedDest->hBitmap = (HBITMAP)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hBitmap, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_MFPICT:
        pMedDest->hMetaFilePict = (HMETAFILEPICT)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hMetaFilePict, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_ENHMF:
        pMedDest->hEnhMetaFile = (HENHMETAFILE)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->hEnhMetaFile, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_FILE:
        pMedSrc->lpszFileName = (LPOLESTR)OleDuplicateData(pMedSrc->lpszFileName, pFmtSrc->cfFormat, NULL);
        break;
    case TYMED_ISTREAM:
        pMedDest->pstm = pMedSrc->pstm;
        pMedSrc->pstm->AddRef();
        break;
    case TYMED_ISTORAGE:
        pMedDest->pstg = pMedSrc->pstg;
        pMedSrc->pstg->AddRef();
        break;
    case TYMED_NULL:
    default:
        break;
    }
    pMedDest->tymed = pMedSrc->tymed;
    pMedDest->pUnkForRelease = NULL;
    if(pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease != NULL)
    {
        pMedDest->pUnkForRelease = pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease;
        pMedSrc->pUnkForRelease->AddRef();
    }
    return S_OK;
}
HRESULT MyDataObject::SetBlob(CLIPFORMAT cf, const void *pvBlob, UINT cbBlob)
{
    void *pv = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, cbBlob);
    HRESULT hr = pv ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        CopyMemory(pv, pvBlob, cbBlob);
        FORMATETC fmte = {cf, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL};
        STGMEDIUM medium = {};
        medium.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        medium.hGlobal = pv;
        hr = this->SetData(&fmte, &medium, TRUE);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            GlobalFree(pv);
        }
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateEnumFormatEtc(UINT cfmt, FORMATETC *afmt, IEnumFORMATETC **ppEnumFormatEtc)
{
    if (cfmt == 0 || afmt == 0 || ppEnumFormatEtc == 0)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    *ppEnumFormatEtc = new MyEnumFormatEtc(afmt, cfmt);
    return (*ppEnumFormatEtc) ? S_OK: E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}

void DeepCopyFormatEtc(FORMATETC *dest, FORMATETC *source)
{
    // copy the source FORMATETC into dest
    *dest = *source;
    if(source->ptd)
    {
        // allocate memory for the DVTARGETDEVICE if necessary
        dest->ptd = (DVTARGETDEVICE*)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(DVTARGETDEVICE));
        // copy the contents of the source DVTARGETDEVICE into dest->ptd
        *(dest->ptd) = *(source->ptd);
    }
}

MyEnumFormatEtc::MyEnumFormatEtc(FORMATETC *pFormatEtc, ULONG nNumFormats)
    :_iRefCount(1),_nIndex(0),_nNumFormats(nNumFormats)
{
    _pFormatEtc  = new FORMATETC[nNumFormats];
    // make a new copy of each FORMATETC structure
    for(ULONG i = 0; i < nNumFormats; i++)
    {
        DeepCopyFormatEtc (&_pFormatEtc[i], &pFormatEtc[i]);
    }
}
MyEnumFormatEtc::~MyEnumFormatEtc()
{
    // first free any DVTARGETDEVICE structures
    for(ULONG i = 0; i < _nNumFormats; i++)
    {
        if(_pFormatEtc[i].ptd)
            CoTaskMemFree(_pFormatEtc[i].ptd);
    }
    // now free the main array
    delete[] _pFormatEtc;
}

HRESULT __stdcall MyEnumFormatEtc::Next(ULONG celt, FORMATETC *pFormatEtc, ULONG *pceltFetched)
{
    ULONG copied = 0;
    // copy the FORMATETC structures into the caller's buffer
    while (_nIndex < _nNumFormats && copied < celt)
    {
        DeepCopyFormatEtc (&pFormatEtc [copied], &_pFormatEtc [_nIndex]);
        copied++;
        _nIndex++;
    }
    // store result
    if(pceltFetched != 0)
        *pceltFetched = copied;
    // did we copy all that was requested?
    return (copied == celt) ? S_OK : S_FALSE;
}
```

7.IDragDemo.h

```
#ifndef _DRAGDROP_H_
#define _DRAGDROP_H_
#include <windows.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#endif //_DRAGDROP_H_
```

Complete Code can be get here:https://github.com/cyfingm/cb_ole_dragdrop

Comment: @piyush @GeorgeStocker I have try to edit the description to show what I am desire and where I stuck at.Is the post ok to be reopen?Help me,please,I`m really confuse with this.

Comment: @piyush Am I post to much code here?

Comment: There's way too much code here. Please pare it down to the absolute minimum needed to demonstrate the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

`OleIsCurrentClipboard()` is returning `S_FALSE` because you are calling `OleFlushClipboard()` beforehand.  Read the documentation:

[OleFlushClipboard function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679707.aspx)

> Carries out the clipboard shutdown sequence. **It also releases the IDataObject pointer that was placed on the clipboard by the OleSetClipboard function.**
>
> ...
>
> OleFlushClipboard renders the data from a data object onto the clipboard **and releases the IDataObject pointer to the data object.**
>
> ...
>
> **Before** calling OleFlushClipboard, you can easily determine if your data is still on the clipboard with a call to the OleIsCurrentClipboard function.

Basically, once you call `OleFlushClipboard()`, the clipboard no longer contains a pointer to your `IDataObject`.  The `CF_HDROP` data gets copied directly onto the clipboard, and the `IDataObject` is removed.

Why are you involving the clipboard at all?  You do not need to put the `IDataObject` on the clipboard in order to use `DoDragDrop()`, so stop doing that.  You pass the `IDataObject` directly to `DoDragDrop()`, that is all you need to do.

There are other problems with this code as well.

This line is wrong:

```
strcpy((char*)(tDropFiles+sizeof(DROPFILES)), tFileName);
```

It should be this instead:

```
strcpy(((char*)tDropFiles)+sizeof(DROPFILES), tFileName);
```

Or this:

```
strcpy((char*)(tDropFiles+1), tFileName);
```

You are also not maintaining the `IDataObject` and `IDropSource` reference counts correctly.  When you create those objects, their reference counts are 0.  `OleSetClipboard()` will increment the `IDataObject` reference count, then `OleFlushClipboard()` will decrement it, freeing that object before `DoDragDrop()` is called.  `Label1EndDrag()` needs to call `AddRef()` on both objects after creating them (it has a reference to them, afterall), and then call `Release()` when it is done using them.

```
pDropSource  = new MyDropSource();
pDropSource->AddRef();

pDataObject  = new MyDataObject((MyDropSource*)pDropSource);//(&fmtetc, &stgmed, 1);
pDataObject->AddRef();

...

pDropSource->Release();
pDataObject->Release();
```

Also, this will not work:

```
(MyDropSource*)pDropSource
```

You cannot create a `MyDropSource` instance, assign it to an `IDropSource*` pointer, and then type-cast it back to `MyDropSource*`.  And besides, there is no good reason to have `MyDataObject` contain a pointer to `MyDropSource` (especially since it is not actually using it for anything, nor is it incrementing/decrementing the reference count), so you need to remove that altogether.

Lastly, your `QueryInterface()` implementations are not returning the correct output pointer address. It is not taking polymorphic vtables into account correctly. The implementation need to look more like this instead:

```
STDMETHODIMP MyDataObject::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)
{
    if (!ppvObject)
        return E_POINTER;

    if (riid == IID_IDataObject)
        *ppvObject = (IDataObject*)this;
    else if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
        *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
    else
    {
        *ppvObject = 0;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    AddRef();
    return S_OK;
}
```

I'm sure there are other flaws and leaks in this code, but I stopped reviewing after seeing these big flaws.  It is not a very clean implementation in general.

**Update**: `DROPEFFECT_NONE` is defined as 0, so the statement

```
if((dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_NONE) == DROPEFFECT_NONE)
```

Will always evaluate as **true**, regardless of the value of `dwEffect`.  Don't use the bitwise `&` operator to test for `DROPEFFECT_NONE`, use the `==` operator instead.  Use `&` for all other values.

```
if(dwEffect == DROPEFFECT_NONE)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Ole data not accepted!!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
else if((dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_MOVE) == DROPEFFECT_MOVE)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Ole data moved!!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
else if((dwEffect & DROPEFFECT_COPY) == DROPEFFECT_COPY)
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Ole data copied!!", "DRAGDROP_S_DROP", 0);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for review my code,sorry for my poor code,I have adopt your advice and resolve some problem,but I have stuck at a another place,I call DoDragDrop,but nothing happend,details is in the post(I just edit it).I debug to find why but I was messed.Could you help me.Source code can be see in github now:[repo](https://github.com/cyfingm/cb_ole_dragdrop).

Comment: also get DROPEFFECT_NONE.I think maybe there`s something wrong with setData:(

Comment: All I can tell you is that you have a very ugly and lengthy implementation.  Rather than wasting time trying to fix it, I suggest you consider getting rid of it completely and use a pre-made Drag&Drop library, such as Ander Melander's [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/) ([update](https://github.com/landrix/The-new-Drag-and-Drop-Component-Suite-for-Delphi)), in particular its `TDropFileSource` component.  All you have to do is give it the filename you want to drag. Let it do all of the hard OLE work for you.

Comment: I`m so sorry for my poor messy code.I try to using third-party component,but I want to know how to implement that:( By now,I have achieve that,I boil down the code and slice long function into few small function.Thank u for your help:). My code is here:[OLE Drag&Drop](https://github.com/cyfingm/CB_OLEDrag-Drop), there is an DragOutDemo.exe to show that:)Thanks